# Image procesing using node js by url

Tags: node.js, image-processing, backend, crop, image-resizing

**Any one have idea about that**

I have to create api for image add ,resize && crop using nodejs

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre], [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sharp, jimp, and gm.